# undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass ruby

Tags: ruby, scorm

i am a newbie in ruby... I'm trying to convert media into a scorm package using what i found on github but i got an error while trying to run the script in the command prompt `` undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass ``. I guess it may be due to a defined method. any idea on how i can remove this error ?

```
dir = ARGV.shift.gsub(/\/+$/, '')
index = nil
media = []
Dir["#{dir}/media/*.json"].each do |file|
  id = JSON.parse(File.read(file))
  base = file.gsub(/\/media\/.*\.json$/, '')
  index = "#{base}/index.html"
  name = File.basename file
  media.push [name,id]
  puts "#{name}: #{id}"
end
```

Comment: `undefined method for nil:NilClass` is similar to a `NullPointerException` (or similar) in other languages, it means one of your variables is nil. At a glance, maybe the first line `ARGV.shift.gsub()` is what's causing the problem, if you invoke this script without passing in command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you are calling the method `gsub` on an object that is an instance of [`NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html), in other words you are calling `gsub` on `nil`.

The error message tells you in which method and on which line this happens and how you got to that line of code. You will have to examine the error message to find the place in your code where you are calling `gsub` on an object that is `nil`, then you have to examine your code to find out why that object is `nil` instead of a `String` as you expect it to.